# How to ensure that messages sent with TTetheringAppProfile.SendStream were delivered properly?

Tags: firemonkey, delphi-xe7, tethering

I have a simple mobile app, that takes a series of photos and sends it via SendStream() to the connected Profile.

```
myTetherAppProfile.SendStream(myTetherManager.RemoteProfiles[idConnected],
                              'ImageData',
                              bmpStreamData);
```

The occurring problem here is that the receiver-app doesn't get all the image-streams depending on the connection-strength (The ResourceReceived-Event isn't triggered on the receiver-app).

This would be no problem if I get a response that the delivery failed. But I don't get this (`SendStream()` returns "True")

Is there a possibility other than implementing a "please answer with another message if you received my image"-function to achieve stable transmissions even with bad connection? Or is App-Tethering by default designed to be lossy?

Also after a big stack of images I sometimes get the "connection reset by peer"-error. (I'm not sure if this error is related to the actual problem, so I preferred posting it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the relevant code from System.Tether.AppProfile (XE8 version), it appears to be a bug. See my inline comments below. Please report to https://quality.embarcadero.com

```
function TTetheringAppProfile.SendStream(const AProfile: TTetheringProfileInfo; const Description: string;
  const AStream: TStream): Boolean;
var
  LProfileInfo: TTetheringProfileInfo;
  LConnection: TTetheringConnection;
  LCommand: TTetheringCommand;
begin
  if not FindProfile(AProfile.ProfileIdentifier, LProfileInfo) then
    raise ETetheringException.CreateFmt(SNoProfile, [AProfile.ProfileIdentifier]);
  CheckProfileIsConnected(AProfile);
  LConnection := GetConnectionTo(AProfile);
  TMonitor.Enter(LConnection);
  try
    LCommand := LConnection.Protocol.SendCommandWithResponse(SendStreamCommand, Version, Description);
    if LCommand.Command = SendStreamOkResponse then
    begin
      Result := LConnection.Protocol.TransferStream(AStream);
      if Result then
      begin    <-- Result here is guaranteed to be True
        LCommand := LConnection.Protocol.ReceiveCommand;
        if LCommand.Command = SendStreamContentOKResponse then
          Result := True;  <-- Sets Result to True if succeeds, 
              <-- but nothing to set Result to False if call failed.
      end;
    end
    else
      Result := False;
  finally
    TMonitor.Exit(LConnection);
  end;
end;
```